# Default AES value of pkzip in jcl on mainframe?

Tags: encryption, zip, aes, mainframe, jcl

I am working with jcls on mainframe with the program pkzip and pkunzip for creating and reading zip files.
I need some information about the AES encryption of creating password protected zip files. I want to know what is the default / standard AES encryption type (128 / 192/ 256 bits) of pkzip?

I know you can set the Parameter in the jcl file but if you won't set it, what will be the default value?

I didn't find any Information in the documentation.

https://www.pkware.com/documents/manuals/PKMU-V5R5000.pdf

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you can specify what pkzip uses: `-AES128` | `-AES192` | `-AES256` are clearly indicated in the document you point to, and CBC mode is specified. And the decryption will detect which one was used from the archive - again as documented.